# Setup Blocked: Tools for Apache Cordova for visual studio 2013-CTP3.1

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to Install Cordova Tools for Visual Studio , but I think because I have the old version of this tool I get this Error Messages.

I try to run the commands on the attached URL on Microsoft Site, no luck 
please , is any one encounter this problem before ?

My computer has Windows 7 installed

Comment: Please email vscordovatools@microsoft.com to get specific guidance on constructing a command that will work with your configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for MultiDeviceHybridApps_VS.msi in your %ProgramData%\Package Cache folder.

Uninstall by running command:

```
msiexec /x <Full path of MultiDeviceHybridApps_VS.msi>
```

in admin cmd window. Then install CTP3.1.