# Apache cordova not installing on VS2013

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2013

I tried to install apache cordova 3 on Visual Studio 2013 ultimate but whenever I install it I get this:
[image]

I tried uninstalling VS2013 and reinstall it without any luck I even tried VS2013 community the same and the provided link seem to be not working because I tried all commands in the documentation and all of them gave me error.

Comment: what was the error you received when running those commands?

Comment: package is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: Run those commands with double quotes around them in cmd prompt.

Comment: I run the command and I got :The system cannot find the path specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved this problem with these steps:

1. Uninstall VS 2013 Update 4.
2. Install VS 2013 Update 3.
3. Install Apache Cordova CTP2 and uninstall it completely
4. Install VS 2013 Update 4.
5. Install Apache Cordova CTP3.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to uninstall Visual Studio 2013.  You need to uninstall VS Tools for Cordova. You probably have this listed in your add/remove programs, separately then Visual Studio 2013.

1. Close all instances of VS.
2. Use add/remove program to remove the program in my attached screenshot.
3. Run the commands listed under resolution on http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3014133
4. Restart PC
5. Always download latest copy from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42675

Do you also happen to have any version of VS 2015 installed?

[image: screenhot]

Comment: Tool for apache doesnot exist in the add remove program

Comment: If the commands don't work for you, try the guidance in this earlier [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466142/setup-blocked-tools-for-apache-cordova-for-visual-studio-2013-ctp3-1)